# Jboss wildfly Java compatibility

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

Can someone please point to a location, where we can find if the jboss  compatibility matrix with Java 10?

I am using wildfly 9.0.2 Final version. Is this compatible with Java 10?

Regards,
Vivek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildfly 9.0.2 was released on Oct 26, 2015 - http://wildfly.org/news/2015/10/26/WildFly902-Released/

Java 10 was released on Mar 20, 2018 - https://www.oracle.com/corporate/pressrelease/Java-10-032018.html.

Hence there is no reason to believe, that Wildfly 9.0.2 can run Java code compiled with JDK 10.

Then again - you can configure Wildfly to run with a custom JVM by setting `JAVA_HOME="/opt/java/..."` in the `standalone.conf` file. As Java is binary backwards compatible, theoretically this would work.

Comment: thanks @tbsalling, I will check with this and shall revert.